# Is it possible to view deployment events in the CLI for CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

In the AWS Console, it is possible to the status of a deployment for individual events on individual instances.

**Is there an equivalent command to do this on the CLI?**

I have looked through [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/index.html) for the `deploy` command tried `get-deployment` but that does not list individual events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the events under "Deployment lifecycle events" in the AWS CodeDeploy console? If yes, then you can retrieve them via following cli commands:

- batch-get-deployment-targets [1] or batch-get-deployment-instances [2]
- get-deployment-instance [3]

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/batch-get-deployment-targets.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/batch-get-deployment-instances.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AWS CodeDeploy agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html)

The AWS CodeDeploy agent must be installed and configured on those instances in order for them to be used in a deployment.

The agent generates three log files:

1. Agent log – Contains information about the agent’s health and
   overall deployment status.
2. Deployment log – Contains STDOUT, STDERR,
   and information specific to the user-defined scripts that run during a deployment.
3. Updater log (Linux agents) – Contains agent updater
   status.

For more and the source of above, follow this :  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/view-aws-codedeploy-logs-in-amazon-cloudwatch-console/

Now once your logs are pushed to Cloudwatch, you can use something like [cwtail](https://github.com/kennu/cwtail) to tail the logs.